# Print Failed tests data on Jenkins Console using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework, jenkins-groovy

I couldn't find any way to print failed test tags, test name, reason etc of a robot framework results on Jenkins Console using Robot plugin or by parsing output.xml

As ChatGPT suggested i have tried to input output.xml to robot() of a robot plugin in jenkins pipeline.
But I'm getting no such property failedTests

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Robot Test') {

            steps {

                script {

                    // Run Robot Framework tests

                    sh 'robot --outputdir results tests'

                    // Parse the Robot Framework output XML file

                    def robotOutput = robot(

                        inputFile: 'results/output.xml',

                        outputPath: 'robot-reports',

                        logFileName: 'log.html',

                        reportFileName: 'report.html',

                        outputFileName: 'output.xml'

                    )

                    // Print failed tags

                    robotOutput.failedTests.each { failedTest ->

                        failedTest.tags.each { tag ->

                            println("Failed tag: ${tag}")

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will be to use the junit plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/
an example:

```
 dir ("app/test-results") {
      junit allowEmptyResults: true, skipPublishingChecks: true, testResults: '*'
 }
```

Comment: my intension is to collect the failed tags, tests and filename and publish to database, so I want these 3 data in a variable.
Is that possible with junit?